# Timevalue function not working for unrecognized time format

Tags: excel, time, format, data-cleaning

I have a bunch of time data that's formated weirdly, ranging from numbers 100 (representing 1 AM, or 01.00.00) to 2359 (representing 11.59PM, or 23.59.00).

I have been trying to use the TIMEVALUE() function to convert these data, but it just returns #Value?, I guess because the time format 'HHMM' is not recognized without the ' : ' separating them?

What I'd like is to convert it to the HH:MM:SS format, where the SS would automatically be zero.

Answer (score 1):

If your text values are consistent, this can be carried out by using a formula that splits the value by the number of characters and then recombines the split values into a time value.

All formulas assume that your weirdly formatted text value is in cell B2

```
=IF(LEN(B2)>3,LEFT(B2,2),LEFT(B2,1))
```

This formula works out the first (hour) element of a time, if the text string is greater than three characters it will take the first 2 characters of the string (23), if its less than 3 characters it will only take the first character (1)

```
=RIGHT(B2,2)
```

This formula takes the second (minute) element of the time.

```
=TIME(C2,D2,0)
```

Finally this formula converts the two text elements into a string

C2 = The cell with formula 1 in it

D2 = The cell with formula 2 in it

This could all be written as the following formula if needed

```
=TIME(IF(LEN(B2)>3,LEFT(B2,2),LEFT(B2,1)),RIGHT(B2,2),0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to work partially, the hours and last digit of numbers is being formatted correctly. Yet the first number of the minutes (0-5) is consistently zero, but only when the hour is a single digit? So 958 becomes 9:08. 1258 Becomes 12:58, correctly.

Comment: can you provide an example of a value that gives a final value that isnt formatted correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my initial reply with an example!

Comment: ive updated my answer now, i made the 2nd formala overly complicated, there was no need to do an if statement as the minutes should always be the last two characters

Comment: or: `=TIME(LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-2),RIGHT(B2,2),0)`

Answer (score 1):

Use REPLACE:

```
=--REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-1,0,":")
```

Then format it as desired.

[image]

[image]